# Who discovered smooth non-analytic functions of a real variable?

Tags: mathematics, real-analysis

Some functions of a real variable are infinitely smooth (have derivatives of all orders) but are not analytic (at some points $a$, the Taylor series at $a$ does not represent the function at any interval around $a$). All sources, such as Wikipedia article [Non-analytic smooth function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function), give about the same example: $f(x)=\exp(-1/x)$ or $f(x)=\exp(-1/x^2)$; the first one is extended by $0$ to the interval $(-\infty,0]$, the other only needs to be defined as $0$ at $x=0$.

But I have not found any references to the origin of these standard examples. Who gave the first example of a smooth non-analytic function of a real variable? Was it a version of the above functions, or something different?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An excellent source for the early history of smooth non-analytic functions is the paper

> Gerald G. Bilodeau. *The origin and early development of non-analytic infinitely differentiable functions*, Arch. Hist. Exact Sci., **27** (1982), 115-135. [MR84g:26017](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=677684).

Also, Dave Renfro wrote an excellent historical *Essay on nowhere analytic $C^\infty$ functions* in two parts (with numerous references). See [1](https://web.archive.org/web/20161009194815/mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=387148) (dated May 9, 2002 6:18 PM), and [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20161009194829/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=387149) (dated May 19, 2002 8:29 PM).

The first example is Cauchy's (in 1823), and is indeed $e^{-1/x^2}$. The point $0$ is what we now call a $(C)$-point (C for Cauchy). Given a smooth function $f$ (defined on an open interval), a point $a$ in its domain is called a $(C)$-point iff  the Taylor series of $f$ about $a$ converges in a positive interval, but the (analytic) function it defines does not coincide with $f$ in any interval centered at $a$.

The other way a smooth function $f$ may fail to be analytic at a point $a$ is if the Taylor series at $a$ has radius of convergence $0$. These points we now call $(P)$-points (P for Pringsheim). The first example is due to du Bois-Raymond in 1876. His example was the function $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)! (x^2 + b_n)}, $$ where we start with a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of non-zero real numbers converging to $0$, and set $b_n = (a_n)^2$. (Again, the $(P)$-point is $0$ in this example.)

The classification into $(C)$- and $(P)$-points is due to Zahorski, who in 1947 published a paper characterizing these points. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/630687/462) for a statement of Zahorski's result, and references.

Du Bois-Raymond's example was the basis for a theorem of Peano, from 1884, that nowadays we name after Borel (namely, the result that any sequence is the sequence of coefficients of the Taylor series about $0$ of a smooth function). Indeed, Peano's result went essentially unnoticed until very recently, when Besenyei publicized it. Borel's version of the result appeared in his thesis, in 1895. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/387897/462) for some details and references.

Comment: Hamilton [gave the same example](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/Received/) $e^{-x^{-2}}$, apparently independently around 1830.